# IOS UIVIEW open as POPUP in autolayout from center of view

Tags: ios, uiview, popup

I have created one `UIview` as subview and I want to show and hide this view from center and the problem is frame changes is not working in autolayout , here is my code but I want to do in autolayout I know nslayout constant changes programmatically please give me solution . -

```
(IBAction)click_button1:(id)sender
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    pop_view.alpha = 0;
    pop_view.frame = CGRectMake (screenRect.size.width/2, screenRect.size.height/2, 0, 0);

    pop_view.hidden = false;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        pop_view.alpha = 1.0;

      // pop_view.frame = CGRectMake (screenRect.size.width/2, screenRect.size.height/2, screenRect.size.width - 20, screenRect.size.height/2);


     pop_view.frame =  CGRectMake
        (
         ( self.view.frame.size.width  / ( CGFloat )2 ) - ( pop_view.frame.size.width  / ( CGFloat )2 ),
         ( self.view.frame.size.height / ( CGFloat )2 ) - ( pop_view.frame.size.height / ( CGFloat )2 ),
         pop_view.frame.size.width,
         pop_view.frame.size.height
         );
    }];


}
```

Comment: You can transform your view, in order to achieve this. I am doing the same thing in my current project but it is in Swift, I can share the code if you want.

Comment: @Nishant You can create an IBOutlet for whichever constraint you want to override programmatically.    IBOutlet var yourConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
EX:- yourConstraint.constant = 100

Comment: so basically what you want to do is center the view right?

Answer (score 0):

Place the pop_view at the center of the view by giving horizontally in container and vertically in container constraints.

[image]

Then give trailing and leading constraints and height for the pop_view.
In `(IBAction)click_button1:(id)sender` you can hide or unhide the view according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already added `pop_view` in your current view and just hiding it

if you only want to center the `pop_view`.

programmatically it will be like this:

```
 .... other declaration ...
 pop_view = popView(); // how ever you instantiate it
 pop_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
 [self.view addSubview:pop_view]; // or whatever your current view is

 // add the constraint to center it horizontally
 [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: pop_view
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                       relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                          toItem: self.view 
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      multiplier: 1
                                                        constant: 0]];

 // Add the constraint to center it vertically
 [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: pop_view
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                       relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                          toItem: self.view 
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      multiplier: 1
                                                        constant: 0]];
```

Then in your IBAction you can just perform the hide/show action